# Clearing a related table property using a filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a table, called `Parent` which has a many-to-many relationship to a table called `Child`. In the EF model, `Parent`is an entity which has a property called `Child` of type `ICollection<Child>`.

I can, in the program, do this to remove all related `Child` elements and then repopulate it:

```
Parent entity = context.Parent.FirstOrDefault(someCondition);
entity.Child.Clear();  // remove all related child elements (in database, only data in the associated table is removed)
entity.Child.Add(newChildEntity)
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, what if I need to remove `Child` elements using a condition?

I tried:

```
entity.Child.Where(otherCondition).Clear();
```

But since `Where` method returns an `IEnumerable<Child>` I cannot use the Clear() method.

Other attempt was to cast to `ICollection<Child>` before calling `Clear` method, but an exception was thrown telling that cast could not be possible.

Any help, please?

Maybe I could get `entity.Child.Where(otherCondition)` and then use a ForEach loop to `Remove` all elements, however, besides providing a very bad performance, I think that way, the `Child` element is also removed, not only the relationship data.

Jaime

Comment: Loop?: `foreach(var c in entity.Child.Where(otherCondition)) { entity.Child.Remove(c); }`

Comment: @mm8 I have done it but how about performance? I tried looking the query, but output windows does not reveal the actual query. Only the `INSERTS` are revealed. I would expect the EF to translate the query to a `DELETE FROM ParentChild WHERE ChildId in (x, y, z)` and not to `DELETE FROM ParentChild WHERE ChildId = x` for every child item.

Comment: If you are concerned with SQL performance, why don't you write and execute raw SQL statements?

Comment: @mm8 mmmmmm, that is a very bad suggestion I guess. Code should be easy to read, easy to understand and following "object oriented programming" principles. Maybe one alternative should be to create a custom extension method, but first, I will try to find out which SQL statement is executed in the server to actual delete the related records.

Comment: *I would expect the EF to translate the query to...* Well, it doesn't. There are third-party libraries that implement bulk delete for EF.

Comment: Bad suggestion? Well, if you are serious about SQL performance, it makes no sense not to write the raw queries yourself. It's actually a bad decision to let EF generate the queries for you if you care about performance. Maybe you should consider using Dapper.

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` method returns an `IEnumerable<Child>`  and you can convert that to list.

Did you try IEnumerable convert to list and clear list ? like this :

```
List<Child> mylist= enumerable.ToList(); 
mylist.Clear();
```

Comment: It does not work because the `ToList`call actually disconnects the related entities from the context. The only way it works is after converting to the list, to execute a `.ForEach(c => entity.Child.Remove(c))`, however, I am wondering how about performance.

Comment: I don't think it will be a problem. Because linq works very fast.

Answer (score -1):

If your dbContext is not something like this then I think you should restructure your database for efficiency.

```
public MyDbContext
{
   //Details obscured for brevity
   public DbSet<Parent> Parents {get; set; }
   public DbSet<Child> Children {get; set;}
}
//Your models
public class Parent
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   //......
}
public class Child
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   //If a child can have just one parent
   public string ParentId {get; set;}
   //......

   public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
//Another table if a child can have more than one parent
public class ParentChild
{
   public string ParentId {get; set;}
   public string ChildId {get; set;}
   //......
   public virtual ICollection<Parent> Parents {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can

```
context.DbSet<Child>().Remove(x => x.ParentId == myParentId);
```

OR

```
context.DbSet<ParentChildren>().Remove(x => x.ParentId == myParentId);
```

Comment: Sorry, but it seems you did not understand the problem. Furthermore, have you used ParentChildren entity? That entity does not actually exist. Mane-to-many relationship uses related properties of type ICollection in both child and parent entities. No intermediate entity exists. By the way, when creating the EF model using Visual Studio, it automatically creates entities and related properties. In SQL Server you do have 3 tables, Parent, Child, and ParentChild tables, but in EF you will not have ParentChild entity.